# text box - setting the precision

Tags: c#

i want to restrict the numbers to be entered on the text box to five precision

eg: 1234.52342
    -1234.52342

how i can restrict while entering the numbers on the text box

Answer (score 1):

Use a MaskedTextBox control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can also use customvalidator control to have restictions on control..Telerik also have a numeric textbox control you can look at  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/radnumerictextbox/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx